# Problem with jquery function.hover

Tags: jquery

I have make a javascript code. This is the code

```
/*************************/
/* twitter ticker        */
/*************************/
var nieuwsbrief_formulier_open = false;
$("#footer a.twitter").hover(

function()
{                   
    if(nieuwsbrief_formulier_open == false)
    {
        nieuwsbrief_formulier_open = true;
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('actief');
        $("#twitter").fadeIn(600);
    }
    else
    {
        nieuwsbrief_formulier_open = false;
        $(this).parent('li').removeClass('actief');
        $("#twitter").fadeOut(600);
    }
    return false;
});
```

When I hover on the `#footer a.twitter`. Then the `#twitter` div come/show. But when I going with the mouse off this `#footer.a.twitter` button. Then the div going away. How can I make, that when I'm going with the mouse over the `#twitter` div. That the div going not away but also show.

Who can help me ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can make a few changes here, the biggest of which is to split your functions.  [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) takes 2 arguments as well, separate handlers for the `mouseleave` and `mouseout` events, like this:

```
$("#footer a.twitter").hover(function() {                   
   $(this).parent('li').addClass('actief');
   $("#twitter").fadeIn(600);
}, function() {
   $(this).parent('li').removeClass('actief');
   $("#twitter").fadeOut(600);
});
```

Then to solve your current issue, since `#twitter` isn't a child (or doesn't appear to be), you need to handle the hover on it, like this:

```
$("#twitter").hover(function() {
   $(this).stop().fadeIn();
}, function() {
   $(this).stop().fadeOut();
});
```